# Ошибка, связанная со шрифтами в Google Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, шрифты, css

> Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/x-font-otf:

http://c2n.me/3cESjKS

Искал решение в Интернете, пишут, что нужно добавить в корневой .htaccess строки

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
```

Никаких изменений...

Что еще можно сделать? Эта проблема на локальной машине в Опен Карте.

Answer (score 1):

Вычитал "Update the configuration for your web server with the following MIME type per font file extension" и "If you are using Apache configuration, you may include the AddType directive for each font type".

Т.е., проблема скорее в настройках сервера (апача). Выложите на хостинг, думаю, все само собой пропадет. Так стоит ли морочиться =)?

В настройках сервера не подскажу. Никогда этим не занимался.

Comment: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess#L251 вот взял отсюда AddType и вставил себе в хтацесс, не помогло....